# issue with scroll to specific part of page(rails + angular)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I have a `polymorphic_path(@review.tool, anchor: "_review_#{@review.id}")`
which generates the url `/software/11#_review_124`
We use angular at front end and angular converts the url to http://url/software/11#/_review_124.

I want to scroll to specific part of the webpage, which has id #some_id but angular is appending a `/ before #` which is preventing  the scroll.

so how to avoid angular to append the trailing slash.
Is there any other work around for this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did it using jquery

```
 var newAddedComment  = $('#'+location.hash.substr(2));
 scrollTop: newAddedComment.offset()
```